# Availability preferences not taken into account in PrestaShop 8 / out_of_stock

Tags: prestashop

Availability preferences not taken into account / out_of_stock

Hello,

The site in question uses Prestashop version 8.

The availability preferences defined in the Quantity or Combinations tab of the product sheet are not taken into account. For example, for a product that is out of stock, the behaviour is "Allow orders". However, on the front page the product appears to be out of stock and cannot be added to the basket.

In the database, out_of_stock is 2  in ps_product and 1 everywhere in ps_stock_available (O=Deny orders - 1=Allow orders - 2=Use global settings here = deny orders). It seems that the value taken into account is that of ps_product, which is confirmed on the front when I modify this value in the database.

After searching, it appears that the source of the problem is the following line: return array_merge($row, self::$productPropertiesCache[$cache_key]); (Product.php - public static function getProductProperties)
This line for the product in question overwrites the correct value in $row. This line sees the value of out_of_stock change for the product in question when the value in ps_product is modified.

This doesn't seem to be the case on a PrestaShop 1.7.8 site, but I can't see where a change needs to be made, unless this issue can be resolved in some other way.

Thanks in advance for yours feedbacks.

Amalia78